# $\alpha^3=\alpha +2$. The ring $\Bbb Z[\alpha] $ is the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q(\alpha) $. How do I compute the prime ideals of norm $\le$ 10?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Let $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ s.t. $\alpha^3=\alpha +2$. The ring $\Bbb Z[\alpha] $ is the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q(\alpha) $. How do I compute the prime ideals of norm less than or equal to 10?

I've seen that in quadratic number fields, to begin with one uses that every prime ideal $P$ in $\mathscr O_K$ has norm $p$ or $p^2$ with $p$ a prime number   but I am unsure that holds here, because this is a cubic  number field. So if the same property does hold were the case, I would say that the prime ideals $P$ I am looking for have $N(P) =2,4,3,9,5,7$. Is this correct so far? How do I continue from here?

---

Edit: completing the solution

$f(x)=x^3-x-2$ is the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$

$f(0)=-2, f(1)=-2,  f(2)=4, f(3)=22,f(4)=58,f(5)=118,f(6)=208$

Reducing mod 3,5 and 7 none of these is never 0 in the respective case, so the reduction mod 3,5 or 7 is always f(x) itself

so $(3) =3\mathscr O_K=(3,\alpha^3-\alpha-2)=(3,0)=(3)$

so $(5) =5\mathscr O_K=(5,\alpha^3-\alpha-2)=(5,0)=(5)$

so $(7) =7\mathscr O_K=(7,\alpha^3-\alpha-2)=(7,0)=(7)$

$(3),(5),(7)$ are all prime

Together with $(2,\alpha) $ and $(2,\alpha +1)$ in the answer all the prime ideals with norm less than or equal to 10 are

$(3),(5),(7),(2,\alpha) $ and $(2,\alpha +1)$

**Is this Ok?  Shouldn't I be analyzing also N(P)=$2^2 , 2^3$ and $3^2$ that have norm less than or equal to 10 as well?**

Edit 2: So checking the norm it looks like actually (3),(5),(7) have norms greater than 10 so  the final correct answer is that $(2,\alpha) $ and $(2,\alpha +1)$ are  all the prime ideals with norm less than or equal to 10

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150038/discussion-on-question-by-darkside-alpha3-alpha-2-the-ring-bbb-z-alpha); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dedekind—Kummer theorem applies for all primes, since $[O_K:\Bbb Z[\alpha]] = 1$ is given.

Modulo $2$: $x^3-x-2 \equiv x^3 + x \equiv x (x^2+1) \equiv x(x+1)^2 \!\! \mod 2$ is the decomposition into irreducible factors. Then, by the theorem, $(2) = 2 O_K = (2,\alpha) (2,\alpha+1)^2$, the ideals $(2, \alpha)$ and $(2, \alpha + 1)$ are prime, and are the only prime ideals that are "above $2$" (Definition 3.2). The norms are multiplicative, and $N((2)) = 2^3 = 8$ (why?), so the norms of the above prime ideals are both $2^1 = 2$.

Note that $(2)$ neither "totally ramifies", nor "remains prime", nor "splits completely".

Comment: Could you please check if the rest of the solution that I posted under edit is correct as well? Shouldn't $N(P)=2^2 , 2^3$and $3^2$ that have norm less than or equal to 10  be analyzed as well?

Comment: That seems fine. (Of course, for a polynomial of degree at least $4$ checking just the roots would be insufficient.) Any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of norm $p^k$ has to contain $p$ and thus $(p)$, so by the reverse inclusion (p. 38 before Proposition) $\mathfrak p$ has to divide $(p)$. So you only have to consider the splitting of $(p)$'s.

Comment: I thought the after you computed the ideals if (2) and with my ideals from the theorem the problem was over... why do I need to observe the only prime ideals that are "above 2" and find the norms of the ideals again that I found? si it like some check that may sometimes fail and could lead to the computed ideals being discarted?
 And how do I compute the norm of  (2)?  I think that I can use$ N((2))= |N_K(2)|$, and for this I need an integral basis of $\mathscr O_K$ and I am not sure if  $1, \alpha$ is an integral basis  to do this?

Comment: After your computations the problem is indeed over, I was just responding to your question. What I meant was that you'll automatically get **every** prime ideal with norm $p^k$, $k$ integer, from the decomposition of $(p)$. The norm of a number $\alpha$ is (up to sign IIRC?) the product of images of $\alpha \in K$ under all $\Bbb Q$-automorphisms of $K$ (or use definition 1.15). Up to sign, it coincides with the ideal norm of $(p)$. But $p$ is rational, so all automorphisms fix it, and $|N(p)| = N((p)) = p^{\deg_{\Bbb Q} K}$. So, in our case, principal ideals other than $(2)$ have norms $>10$.

Comment: So my answer was incorrect then. My answer was that the prime ideal with norm less than or equal to 10 are the two that you found plus (3),(5),(7). In our case deg$_{\Bbb Q}K=3$ (right?), so the norms are $3^3, 5^3$ and $7^3$ and therefore they don't have norm $\le 10$. There only $(2,\alpha)$ are $(2,\alpha +1)$ are the only prime ideals with norm $\le 10$

Comment: Yes, I think so.