# Questions about ideal decompositions in the ring of integers of the cubic number field given by $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ s.t. $\alpha^3=\alpha +2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ s.t. $\alpha^3=\alpha +2$. The ring $\Bbb Z[\alpha] $ is the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q(\alpha) $.

(i) Compute all prime ideals  $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ of norm $\le 10.$
The answer is $(2,\alpha), (2,\alpha +1)$
This was proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801524).

(ii) What is the number of nonzero ideals  of $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ of norm $≤ 10 $?

Since every ideal factorizes as a product of prime ideals, and given the result in point (i), the ideals I am looking for are  those of the form $I_{a,b}=(2,\alpha)^a, (2,\alpha +1)^b$ with $N(I_{a,b})\le 10$  so $2^a 2^b\le10 \implies a+b \le 3 $. Then $(a,b)\in \{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(3,0)\}.$ So there are 10 ideals with norm $\le 10$.

(iii) Show that the nonzero ideals of $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ of norm $≤ 10$ are principal.

This looks like a contradiction. If the solution in the previous point is correct all the ideals that I found except (1) have  norm $ ≤ 10$ and are generated by 2 elements or more, aren't they?  For instance $(2,\alpha)$ has two generators, so it cannot be principal.
**What is going on?**

(iv) Which prime numbers ramify in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$? Compute their factorization in $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$.

**1. Is my solution of point (ii)  ok?**

**2. How do I solve (iii) and (iv)?**

**Edit.** In point iii), now it is clear that those ideals such are $(2,\alpha)$ are really principal because of the relation between 2 and $\alpha$ as explained in the answer below. To prove this I would suppose that there exists $\theta \in \Bbb Z$ such that $(\theta)=I_{a,b}$. Then passing to the norm $N((\theta))=N(I_{a,b})=2^{a+b}$, $a, b$ as in the previous point.
To calculate this norm I guess I need the three embedings determined by sending one root of the polynomial to the others. Let $\beta, \overline\beta$ be the other 2 roots which are complex conjugate. So the embeddings are the identity, $\sigma_1:\alpha \mapsto \beta$ and the one that sends $\sigma_2:\alpha \mapsto \overline \beta$. But how do I compute   $N((\theta))$ then?

Comment: problem 14 of chapter 3 in the numbers fields book https://www.radbouduniversitypress.nl/site/books/m/10.54195/IPVU4488/

Comment: Your answer to (ii) looks good to me. For (iv), it is known that a prime number ramifies iff it divides the discriminant of the number field. So compute the discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, take all of its prime factors and compute their decompositions which can be done by using Dedekind-Kummer, as explained in the answers and comments to the question you linked.

Comment: An additional suggestion: It is way easier to read the title of a question if it is not full of mathematical symbols and abbreviations. ;)

Comment: @russoo it's because without the abbreviations I exceed the allowed length. What title do you suggest?

Comment: maybe "Questions about ideal decompositions in a cubic number field" or something like that...?

Comment: Often the simplest way to calculate the norm of an element is to look at its minimal polynomial (when the element generates the entire field). If $m(x)\in\Bbb{Q}(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of an element $\theta$, and $\deg m(x)=n$, we have the result
$$N_{\Bbb{Q}(\theta)/\Bbb{Q}}(\theta)=(-1)^n m(0).$$
In other words, the constant term of the minimal polynomial up to sign. Here we have $n=3$ for all the non-rational elements of the bigger field. And for all algebraic integers $\theta\mid N(\theta)$ because the norm is also the product of conjugates.

Comment: (cont'd) So to find the norms of $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$, just find their minimal polynomials, and check out the constant terms.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Do i need to find $\alpha$ explicitly?, then it would be by Cardanos' formula :$x = 1/3 ( 
 \sqrt[3]{ 27 - 3 \sqrt 78)}+  \sqrt[3]{ 27 + 3 \sqrt 78)})$ but I am not sure how to find the min polynomial in $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$. I guess first I need to know what the elements there look like

Comment: I don't think so. Surely it is simpler to do arithmetic with just powers of $\alpha$, and using the relation $\alpha^3=\alpha+2$ whenever a higher power appears. That is, in comparison to manipulating powers of that monstrous output of Cardano. Besides, the cubic has three distinct roots in $\Bbb{C}$ (only one of them real). Denoting the root just $\alpha$ means that anything you can calculate applies equally to all three roots. You don't need to single out one of them!

Comment: Oh, and if $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)=x^3-x-2$, then surely $\alpha+1$ is a root of $f(x-1)$. May be you could spend more time with just field extensions and minimal polynomials, and only then dive into algebraic number theory, prime ideals and such?

Answer (score 1):

(iii) only:

We have $\alpha^3=\alpha+2$, implying that $$2=\alpha^3-\alpha=\alpha(\alpha^2-1).$$ So one of the generators of the first prime ideal is a multiple of the other.

A similar argument works for the other prime ideal of norm two.

Comment: Remember to check the norms of the generators!

Comment: So if this is for the case $(2,\alpha)$, since 2 is a multiple of $\alpha$, does it mean  $(2,\alpha)=(\alpha)$ ?

Comment: Correct, @darkside

Comment: uhmm strange how Dedekind-Kummer theorem yields  these overparametrized ideals. Is what I wrote in the Edit regarding iii) ok?

Comment: You will often end up needing two generators for a prime ideal. The prime ideals are all principal if and oly if the class number of the field is $h=1$. I'm sure $h$ will be discussed shortly in your book.